# Nonlinear ODE eigenvalue problem

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, eigenvalues

How does one find eigenvalues $\lambda$ of the following problem?

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 u}{\mathrm{d}x^2} = \lambda \left( -u + u^2 \right),$$

$$ u(0) = u(1) = 0. $$

Can this be tackled by Mathematica's built-in method `DEigensystem`? It seems like the right-hand side of the equation must have the form $\lambda u$ only to make `DEigensystem` work.

Comment: A non-linear eigenvalue problem is a bit strange to think about.  I'm not even sure that there would be a point spectrum:  it might be the case that there would be a solution for uncountably many values of $\lambda$ (rather than countably many, as with a linear system.)  Are you sure this problem is well-posed?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert what did u mean by point spectrum? Is it a set of _discrete_ eigvalues on the complex plane, which is the usual case of a linear EVP? Thus its counterpart should be a continuous spectrum for a nonlinear EVP? Am i right? Thanks~

Comment: @user55777:  Basically, yes.  If you look at my answer below, the linear equation has only a discrete set of values of $\lambda$ for which there is a non-zero solution for $u$.  But for the non-linear equation, it appears that any value of $\lambda$ will work.  (The "point spectrum" terminology comes from [some advanced mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis)).)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks for the reply. i just learned the usage of `ParametricNDSolve`. Btw, you mentioned it returned a `InterpolatingFunction`, but i saw it returned a `ParametricFunction` object in MMA's help. Did u meant a `ParametricFunction` belongs to `InterpolatingFunction`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We want to find the value of $\lambda$ for which there exists a solution of the differential equation $u'' = \lambda ( - u + u^2)$, subject to the boundary conditions $u(0) = u(1) = 0$.  We can do this by a shooting algorithm, i.e., solving the related initial value problem
$$
u'' = \lambda (- u + u^2), \qquad u(0) = 0, \; u'(0) = v.
$$
The value of $u(1) \equiv b$ can then be seen to be a function of $\lambda$ and $v$.  If we can find the value(s) of $\lambda$ and $v$ for which $b = 0$, then we have solved this "eigenvalue" problem.

To do this, we can use `ParametricNDSolve`, viewing $\lambda$ and $v$ as "parameters".  We can then use `ContourPlot` to visualize the values of $\lambda$ and $v$ for which $u(1) = 0$.  Here, the function `boundaryval` returns $u(1)$.  A wrinkle occurs because this ODE, being non-linear, does not always have a solution over the full range $[0,1]$ for arbitrary initial conditions at 0;  and sometimes the range of the `InterpolatingFunction` returned by `ParametricNDSolve` does not include $x = 1$.  To account for this, we use `Check`;  if the `InterpolatingFunction` returns the error `dmval`, we know that there is not a solution of this ODE on the domain $[0,1]$ for these parameters, and we return `Null` instead of a numerical value.

```
eqns = {u''[x] == λ (-u[x] + u[x]^2), u[0] == 0, u'[0] == v}
sol = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, u, {x, 0, 1}, {λ, v}]
boundaryval[λ_, v_] := Check[u[λ, v][1] /. sol, Null, {InterpolatingFunction::dmval}]
ContourPlot[boundaryval[λ, v] == 0, {λ, -100, 100}, {v, -20, 20},
  FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

(This plot took about 5 minutes to generate on my laptop.)

The line at $v = 0$ comes from the fact that when $v = 0$, the solution to the ODE is $u(x) = 0$ for all $x$, regardless of the value of $\lambda$.  This central line therefore corresponds to the trivial solution to the equation.  However, the curved lines correspond to non-zero values of $\lambda$ and $v$ that yield $u(1) = 0$;  and it appears that there exists at least one non-zero solution to the original "eigenvalue" problem for *any* value of $\lambda$, including negative values.  Note that for small values of $v$, the curves intersect the $\lambda$ axis at $\pi^2 \approx 9.9$, $4 \pi^2 \approx 39.5$, and $9\pi^2 \approx 88.8$;  these correspond to solutions that remain small ($u \ll 1$) over the whole domain, and so the solutions are "nearly linear".  In this limit, we recover the eigenvalues $n^2 \pi^2$ of the linear problem.

(I'm not sure whether the "dotted" lines are real solutions or spurious.  I believe they correspond to the borders of regions in the $\lambda v$-plane where the initial value problem cannot be solved over the whole domain $[0,1]$.)

To see why we have discrete eigenvalues in the linear case but continuous eigenvalues in the non-linear case, we can also apply the same technique to the linear version of this equation:

```
lineareqns = {u''[x] == λ (-u[x]), u[0] == 0, u'[0] == v}
sol = ParametricNDSolve[lineareqns, u, {x, 0, 1}, {λ, v}]
boundaryval[λ_, v_] := Check[u[λ, v][1] /. sol, Null,{InterpolatingFunction::dmval}]
ContourPlot[boundaryval[λ, v] == 0, {λ, -100, 100}, {v, -20, 20}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

(This plot is generated much more quickly by Mathematica—about 10 seconds on my machine.)

We can see that other than the line $v = 0$, the contours for which $b(\lambda,v) = 0$ are vertical lines, and thus only discrete values of $\lambda$ are eigenvalues of this equation.

What's going on?  In the linear case, suppose that $\{\lambda,v\}$ is a solution of $b(\lambda, v) = 0$.  This means that there exists a solution $u(x)$ such that $u(0) = 0$, $u'(0) = v$, and $u(1) = 0$.  But since the equation is linear for a fixed value of $\lambda$, $\tilde{u}(x) = \alpha u(x)$ will be a solution with $\tilde{u}(0) = 0$, $\tilde{u}'(0) = \alpha v$, and $\tilde{u}(1) = 0$, and with the same value of $\lambda$.  Since this is true for any value of $\alpha$, it must be the case that varying $v$ does not change $b$ when $b = 0$.  In other words, for the linear equation,
$$
b(\lambda, v) = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \left( \frac{\partial b}{\partial v} \right)_\lambda = 0.
$$
Thus, the "curves" of constant $b$ in the $\lambda v$-plane point directly in the $v$-direction.  No such argument can be made for the non-linear equation, since for a fixed value of $\lambda$, a multiple of a solution $u(x)$ to the ODE is generally not itself a solution.