# Understand NDEigensystem::stlin

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve Eq.3 and reproduce Fig.2 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.2795.pdf) using `NDEigensystem` but fail, what is wrong with my code?

```
v0 = 0.25; c = 0;
v[x_, a_] := v0 Tanh[x/a];
systm[a0_, b0_] := 
 Module[{a = a0, b = b0}, {vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{
      (B'[x] + (b + c x ) B[x])^2 + v[x, a] A[x],
      (A'[x] - (b + c x ) A[x])^2 - v[x, a] B[x], 
      DirichletCondition[{A[x] == 0, B[x] == 0}, True]}, {A[x], 
      B[x]}, {x, -20, 20}, 4, 
     Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
{"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 40/400}}}, 
       "Eigensystem" -> "Direct"}];
  ]
```

It gives the following warning when calling `systm[1, 0]`

> NDEigensystem::stlin: Coefficients and boundary conditions need to be stationary and linear.

Comment: **it gives this error** it can't possibly give any error, as there was no call made to the function `systm`. if a call was made, then you need to show the actual call also.

Comment: You also seem to have basic programming error. You define `v` as function taking `x` only as argument. But it uses `a` inside it. Where is it reading this `a` value from? It remains undefined (i.e. symbol).   You set `a=a0` inside the module, but when calling `v[x]` the `a` being used is not the same `a` inside the module.  One is global and the other is local `a`. so better to defined `v` as `v[x_,a_]` and pass it the `a` from the module so it has actual value when used.

Comment: @Nasser, thanks for the comments! actually, I got the error after calling `systm[1, 0]` . I implemented your comments but still get the same error

Comment: You say **I am trying to solve coupled ODE** if so, why not use `NDSolve` ? Why use NDEigensystem?  If you want to actually use NDEigensystem, then yes, it can not do it. I get same error "Coefficients and boundary conditions need to be stationary and linear".  May be someone knows what this means. I searched for it and could not find other references so far.

Comment: But as a hint, if you actually try to solve the system, NDSolve gives solutions, but with warnings **NDSolve`FEM`InitializePDECoefficients::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.** so may these are related. I do not know.

Comment: I think the warning is clear enough. "Coefficients need to be linear." But your operator involves nonlinear term like `(B'[x] + (b + c x ) B[x])^2`. Notice eigenvalue problem (in usual sense) is only defined for linear operator. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenvalues_and_eigenfunctions_of_differential_operators If you're trying to reproduce certain cutting-edge result (I won't be surprised if eigenvalue for nonlinear differential operator is studied somewhere), please clarify.

Comment: @xzczd do you think a more clear error would have been `Operator need to be linear`? I read the error message 3 times and was not sure if it means coefficients in boundary conditions or what coefficients it meant, as it was generic message for me. I do not think the error message was very clear. At least it could be made more clear and specific. But you make good points about linearity of operators and eigevalues.

Comment: @xzczd, I would like to solve  Eq.3 of this [pepar](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.2795.pdf) and reproduce Fig.2

Comment: @Nasser I agree. Actually in **Possible Issues** section of `NDEigensystem` the corresponding statement is "The operator and possible boundary conditions need to be stationary and linear". Also, it's a bit strange that this warning message doesn't have a separate document page.

Comment: Then why are you not just using `NDSolve` to solve those coupled odes in equation (3)?

Comment: @Nasser, I would like to get the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions, how can I do that with `NDSolve`?

Comment: …Your understanding for the differential operator is wrong. $ (\frac{∂}{∂x}+ k)^2\phi \neq (\frac{∂}{∂x} \phi+ k \phi)^2$.

Comment: @xzczd,  that is a pity and embarrassing! I will modify it accordingly..thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though the system itself turns out to be wrong (OP has misunderstood the differential operator $\left(\frac{∂}{∂x}+ k\right)^2$), this seems to be the first question about `stlin` warning in this site, so let me turn the comments to an answer.

Eigenvalue problem (in usual sense) is only defined for linear operator, see [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenvalues_and_eigenfunctions_of_differential_operators) for more info. `NDEigensystem` follows this definition, but your operator involves nonlinear term like `(B'[x] + (b + c x ) B[x])^2`, thus the warning pops up. As the warning message says:

> Coefficients need to be linear.

This warning message is also explained in **Possible Issues** section of document of `NDEigensystem`, the corresponding statement is

> The operator and possible boundary conditions need to be stationary and linear.

which is a bit easier to understand. (It's strange that this warning message doesn't have a separate document page. )

BTW, there does exist attempt to study eigenvalue problem for nonlinear operator in this site, see:

[Nonlinear ODE eigenvalue problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174346/1871)